# Deploying Azure Solution from Dev to test server

Tags: deployment, azure

I'm developing a windows azure solution on VS2012, where i have many projects under the solution and i have on starter project which is xxx.Local.Client

I'm using Azure emulator to emulate the windows azure environment. 
I need to move the solution to a test server while having also to deploy it on the emulator. i packaged my project but still don't know what files should i move to the test server and where should i host the files and how should i configure the server to run the application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by *test server* but... The local emulator runs on the same machine as your development environment (which you've already been using). Then there's Windows Azure Cloud Services, Virtual Machines, or Web Sites that you can deploy to.

If you're referring to a standalone server in your local network to use for an Azure testbed, that configuration doesn't exist (that would be something like an Azure appliance machine).

Depending on what you're testing, you may be able to push your code to Azure Web Sites (assuming you're not running any custom startup scripts or attempting to modify the virtual machines), and you can use Web Sites' free tier. If you need more customization options, you can deploy to Cloud Services (and Visual Studio makes it very easy to do so).

Comment: Thanks , well i needed to do what is not possible to be done as per your answer David. Thanks